# How can I add a zero to dates in a string so all months are 2 characters?

Tags: python

I haved dates in this format:

```
bd1 = '05/27/2018      SW1604-3'
```

And this format:

```
bd2 = '9/16/2021      SU1'
```

I am using `dparser` to remove the extra text which works for dates in the format of `bd1`.

```py
>>> import dateutil.parser as dparser
>>> str(dparser.parse(bd1,fuzzy=True)).split(" ")[0]
'2018-05-27'
```

However I notice that if the dates are not the same length, as is the case for `bd2` (i.e 9 instead of 09), I get an error message:

```py
>>> import dateutil.parser as dparser 
>>> str(dparser.parse(bd2,fuzzy=True)).split(" ")[0] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Noah Siegel\.conda\envs\webvitals\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1368, in parse  
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Noah Siegel\.conda\envs\webvitals\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 643, in parse   
    raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 9/16/2021      SU1
```

Comment: This format is braindead anyway, your future self will thank you for converting to machine-readable (and human-readable to boot!) standard ISO yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: Why not use `datetime.strptime()`?

Comment: @tripleee I am trying to get to this format. `str(dparser.parse(bd1,fuzzy=True)).split(" ")[0]` returns `'2018-05-27'` but `str(dparser.parse(bd2,fuzzy=True)).split(" ")[0]` returns an error

Comment: Problem seems to be in those weird 'SW1604-3' and 'SU1' "suffixes".  Putting on my detective's hat, I think you wanted to do `dparser.parse(bd2.split()[0], fuzzy=True)`

Comment: That does not give the desired output. I am expecting to get '2021-09-16' with `bd2`, which is the same format as the output of  `str(dparser.parse(bd1,fuzzy=True)).split(" ")[0]`.

Comment: Try your code with `bd3 = '09/16/2021      SU1'` and you'll get the same error that you do with `bd2`.  So as has been said, it's these "suffixes" that are the cause of the problem, not the lack of a leading zero.

Comment: @slothrop you are right, adding a leading zero does not solve the issue. I was able to solve the issue but StackOverflow will not let me post an answer to this question for some reason. I will make a new question with the answer I came up with.