# How can I convert strings with dates and suffixes into ISO format?

Tags: python

This is a follow-up to a previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72955841/how-can-i-add-a-zero-to-dates-in-a-string-so-all-months-are-2-characters?noredirect=1#comment128869833_72955841).

I want to know how I can convert a string that has dates and suffixes into a date in ISO format.

Example:

```py
# I have a dataframe of various dates in this format
bd1 = '05/27/2018      SW1604-3'
bd2 = '9/16/2021      SU1'
```

`dparser` works at converting the first string the desired format by not the second

```py
>>> import dateutil.parser as dparser
>>> str(dparser.parse(bd1,fuzzy=True)).split(" ")[0]
'2018-05-27'
```

For some reason the second string returns an error

```py
>>> import dateutil.parser as dparser 
>>> str(dparser.parse(bd2,fuzzy=True)).split(" ")[0] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Noah Siegel\.conda\envs\webvitals\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1368, in parse  
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Noah Siegel\.conda\envs\webvitals\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 643, in parse   
    raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 9/16/2021      SU1
```

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging the code a little bit solves the issue for me and I didn't get any errors with the rest of the strings in my dataset.

```py
>>> import dateutil.parser as dparser
>>> bd1 = '05/27/2018      SW1604-3'
>>> bd2 = '9/16/2021      SU1'
>>> dt = dparser.parse(bd1.split()[0], fuzzy=True)
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2018-05-27'
>>> dt = dparser.parse(bd2.split()[0], fuzzy=True)
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2021-09-16'
```

I am not sure why `str(dparser.parse(bd1,fuzzy=True)).split(" ")[0]` works in some cases but...

```py
dt = dparser.parse(bd1.split()[0], fuzzy=True)
dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

works in at least all the data I am working with so if there is someone much better versed in python than I am I would love here why this works.

Comment: Why does it work? Because you're isolating the date portion from whatever comes after it, and the parser has a much easier time without having to decide whether the extraneous characters are meaningful or not.